# SQL count using subquery

Tags: sql

I have a table `users` that lists all users who have entered orders in to the system.

Each order has a `order_number` and `user` amongst a ton of other columns.

Each week I am looking to get a list of the total orders that each user has entered in to the system, I guess this will need a subquery. I have looked at grouping and subquery but am really lost.

The idea is to `SELECT` a count of orders entered that week, `entry_date` between `sysdate` and `sysdate-5` etc. which I don't have a problem doing, but I don't understand how to then count it per user.

So for e.g. Jane entered 150 orders, Steve entered 450 orders etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: You may want to post the schema for your various tables to help people formulate their answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really think you need a sub-query.   Won't a GROUP BY solve your problem?

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE - 5 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY USER
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY. I made up some column names.

```
SELECT u.user, COUNT(*) FROM orders o, users u 
WHERE o.user = u.user AND o.entry_date BETWEEN o.sysdate - 5 AND o.sysdate 
GROUP BY u.user
```